# Is the parallel degree silently ignored?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

My query is the following :

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE MODIFY LOB(DOCUMENT) (SHRINK SPACE);
```

The parallel degree for the table is 1 :

```
SELECT DEGREE FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEE';
```

Result : 1

Table EMPLOYEE is not partitioned.

If I launch the same query with a parallel degree, the system does not complain, but is it silently ignored ?

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE MODIFY LOB(DOCUMENT) (SHRINK SPACE) PARALLEL 8;
```

Any chance that the query will be faster ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDL operations will run in parallel when:

- The degree of the table is not 1

OR

- The session parallel ddl has been enabled by `alter session enable parallel ddl`

Anyway, you should always run the alter session enable parallel ddl before running any DDL operation that can run in parallel. Although the documentation did not say that shrink can run in parallel, the syntax is allowed, so I guess you can test whether it runs faster or not.

The parallel DDL statements for nonpartitioned tables and indexes are:

```
CREATE INDEX

CREATE TABLE AS SELECT

ALTER INDEX REBUILD
```

The parallel DDL statements for partitioned tables and indexes are:

```
CREATE INDEX

CREATE TABLE AS SELECT

ALTER TABLE {MOVE|SPLIT|COALESCE} PARTITION

ALTER INDEX {REBUILD|SPLIT} PARTITION
```

Example

```
SQL>  create table t ( c1 clob ) ;

Table created.

SQL> alter table t  MODIFY LOB(c1)  (SHRINK SPACE) PARALLEL 8 ;

Table altered.
```

Instead of SHRINK you can always move the segment lob, which I can assure 100% will run in parallel and faster. The problem is that if you have indexes, there will become invalid.

UPDATE

To move the lob segment, you must do the following

Moving LOB:

```
SQL> spoolmovelob.sql
SET HEADING OFF
SET pagesize 200
SET linesize 200
select 'ALTER TABLE <owner>.'||TABLE_NAME||' MOVE LOB('||COLUMN_NAME||') STORE AS (TABLESPACE <Tablespace_name>) parallel 5 nologging;' from dba_lobs where TABLESPACE_NAME='<Tablespace_name>';

Note: The above query will include all the LOB,LOBSEGMENT,LOBINDEXES
```

Moving Table:

```
SQL> spool /home/oracle/moveTables.sql
SET HEADING OFF
SET PAGESIZE 200
SET LINESIZE 200
select ' ALTER TABLE <owner>.'||TABLE_NAME||' MOVE TABLESPACE <Tablespace_name>) parallel 5 nologging;' from dba_tables where owner='<owner name>';
```

Moving Indexes:

```
SQL> spool /home/oracle/moveIndex.sql
SET HEADING OFF
SET long 9999
SET linesize 200
select 'alter index <owner>.'||index_name||' from dba_indexes 'rebuild tablespace <Tablespace_name>)   online parallel X nologging;' where owner='<owner>.';
```

Remember to replace X with the specific degree.

Comment: how do I move the segment lob and rebuild the indexes ?

Comment: do all indexes become invalid or only the ones including the blob column?

Comment: in 12c you cannot create indexes over lob columns. It produces ORA-02327

Comment: if you move only the LOB, the indexes over the other columns will not be affected

Comment: @Sybuser, can you upvote the answer if it helped you ? really appreciated

Comment: I move only the LOB indeed. I just have to do :

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE MOVE LOB(DOCUMENT) STORE AS (TABLESPACE MYTABLESPACE) parallel 5 nologging;

Right?

Comment: If the LOB is already located in a tablespace called MYTABLESPACE, can it simply be put like this : ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE MOVE LOB(DOCUMENT) parallel 5 nologging;

Comment: yes , you can omit tablespace, but you need to specify store clause. for example ` alter table tetlob move lob(c1) store as securfile parallel 5`

Comment: I got "ORA-01502 index or partition of such index is in unusable state" after using the table altered by the move lob command. What should be done?

Comment: @Sybuser, rebuilding the index. If it is a partitioned index , check dba_ind_partitions to see which one is in unusable state. then `alter index owner.index_name rebuild partition partition_name parallel`

Comment: meanwhile I did : 
ALTER INDEX THE_INDEX REBUILD ONLINE PARALLEL 63 NOLOGGING;

Comment: that is ok. rebuild online takes more time, but allows accessing the index meanwhile. why parallel 63 ? if you enable parallel ddl, and you use rebuild online parallel, Oracle will decide the best degree for the operation

Comment: 63 came from http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_fastest_way_to_rebuild_oracle_index.htm

Comment: @Sybuser, you should not use a fix degree. It is better let Oracle decide which is the best degree for the operation.

Comment: so the queries would look like this: 
ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DDL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE MOVE LOB(DOCUMENT) STORE AS SECUREFILE PARALLEL NOLOGGING;
ALTER INDEX THE_INDEX REBUILD ONLINE PARALLEL NOLOGGING;

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable parallel ddl?
`alter session force parallel ddl parallel 8`

Show us your session parameters:

```sql
select * 
from v$ses_optimizer_env e
where e.sid=userenv('sid')
and (
    name like '%parallel%'
 or name like '%cpu%'
 or name like '%optim%'
)
order by name
```

Comment: it says "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist". Is this because I'm non-admin ?

Comment: The alter session command completed normally, though.

Comment: @Sybuser just ask your DBA's to grant you `grant read on v_$ses_optimizer_env to your_user`

Comment: you can't access the v$ without an user who has SELECT ANY DICTIONARY or SELECT CATALOG ROLE, normally not granted by DBAs to application users. Of course, it could be granted directly by `grant select on v_$session to xxxx;`

Comment: @RobertoHernandez depends on the exact 'v$' view. For example v$session is often granted to public.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov, well I guess that depends on where you have worked. On my particular experience, DBAs where always not very happy to grant select over v$views, not even v$session, something which I honestly don't understand.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez as I'm a DBA partly, I know that many well-designed applications need access to some views. And obviously it's much more dangerous to grant 'SELECT ANY DICTIONARY or SELECT CATALOG ROLE' than just direct new `read` (not `select`) grant

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov, you are right, however in real life things are not always as easy. In the  ITIL model, most of the DBAs I knew are just database operators which not so much knowledge, and they never understood the need of some things. Don't get me wrong, i am totally agreed with you, but I wish other DBAs would know what you know ;)

Answer (score 1):

Accroding to the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/types-parallelism.html#GUID-365F1095-6434-44E2-AE16-F2777EDC82F1)
the ALTER TABLE MODIFY operation cannot be run in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

> If I launch the same query with a parallel degree, the system does not complain, but is it silently ignored ?

Depending on how your database in general and your specific seession are configured, it may be ignored.

> Any chance that the query will be faster ?

This will very much depend on your specific dataset, your available system resources, and how you set up your parallelism. Pay attention to the parallel_degree_policy setting; it controls default behavior.

See the Oracle whitepaper, "[Parallel Execution with Oracle Database](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/twp-parallel-execution-fundamentals-133639.pdf)" for a more complete understanding. In particular, read the section on "Controlling Parallel Execution" beginning on page 21.